# Amenability of a directed union

Tags: topological-groups, amenability

I have the following statement: if all groups in the directed system  $\{G_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ are amenable, then so is their directed union $G:= \bigcup_{i\in I}G_{i}$
(Remember that a group is amenable if it admits a finitely aditive and left invariant measure.  In the proof below, each $G_{i}$ has measure $\mu_{i}$.)

Let $M_{i} := \{\mu:\mathit{P}(G)\longrightarrow [0,1] \mbox{ such that } \mu \mbox{ is finitely aditive measure and } \mu(gA)=\mu(A) \forall g\in G_{i}\}$

Note that each $M_{i}$ is nonempty since we can define $\mu(A):= \mu_{i}(A\cap G_{i})$.  Also, we have that $[0,1]^{\mathit{P}(G)}$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem and that each $M_{i}$ is closed  in $[0,1]^{\mathit{P}(G)}$.

I do not see why the $M_{i}$ are closed in $[0,1]^{\mathit{P}(G)}$.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an important thing: you want to have a finitely additive $G$-invariant **probability** measure. In fact, the fact that $\mu (G) =1$ give you directly that the sets are closed.

If I can give you an advice, using **the fixed point criterion for amenable groups** the proof is more elegant and easier.